# SvelteKit Load Data At Root in Background

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am new to SvelteKit and trying to load an onnxruntime model in routes/+page.js's load function. This takes like ~10 seconds to load, and currently, the whole site hangs until the loading is complete. How do I show some sort of basic UI while this loading is taking place?

I tried

```
<script>
    import {navigating} from '$app/stores'
</script>

{#if $navigating}
    <h1>Loading Model</h1>
{:else}
    <slot/>
{/if}
```

in `+layout.svelte` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you return a promise from a sub-property of the data, it will be streamed (if supported by the platform), the promise then can be awaited via [`{#await ...}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-await) on the page. See [documentation on this feature](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises).

If this is not an option you could start a `fetch` from the page to a custom endpoint/API route ([`server.js`/`ts` file](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server)).